# threads are WAITING in the ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpool

This code runs very slow. I dumped the threads, and nearly one thread is running at the same time, but when I change the `ExecutorService` to `ForkJoinPool`, the code runs very fast. I don't know why the threads are waiting, my computer has 8 cores...

[image]

```
public class Tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int NUM_OF_THREADS = 8;
        int NUM_OF_INCREMENTS = 100_000_000;
        //ExecutorService service = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        final Counter counter = new StupidCounter();

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_INCREMENTS; i++) {
            service.submit(newCounterClient(counter, i));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - before);
        System.out.println(counter.getCounter());
    }


    static class CounterClient implements Runnable {
        private Counter counter;
        private int num;

        public CounterClient(Counter counter, int num) {
            this.counter = counter;
            this.num = num;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            counter.increment();
        }
    }

    static interface Counter {
        void increment();

        long getCounter();
    }

    static class StupidCounter implements Counter {
        long i = 0;

        @Override
        public void increment() {
            i++;
        }

        @Override
        public long getCounter() {
            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
"pool-1-thread-7" #17 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007faaa481c000 nid=0x6503 waiting on condition [0x0000700001d6d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c006b3d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1222)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(617Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to draw any *real* conclusions from this code, since it doesn't really *do* anything. The internal queue of the executor is the bottleneck, that's why you only see 1 thread "working" at a time. It's not really working, it's getting the next task from the queue, making all the other threads (which are also getting the next task) wait. You're not really testing anything here, except the functionality of `LinkedBlockingQueue.take()`.

The `increment()` method is not thread-safe so basically you're testing bad code and the results are pretty much irrelevant. If you make the `CounterClient` task perform actual work, that takes multiple milliseconds, you'll see a lot smaller difference (if any) in the performance compared to `ForkJoinPool`.

Answer (score 0):

When using the FixedThreadPool most of the time is used for GarbageCollection since the program consumes a lot of it. I tried execution with VM parameter *-Xmx3g* and still got stuck in Garbage Collection while the VM was trying to avoid running out of memory.

You might want to use a Memory Dump to dive into the root cause of the consumption, but I have a guess it is the **long** instances in the counter.

Anyway, the root cause seems to be the *FixedThreadPool* using a *LinkedBlockingQueue* as *workQueue*. Because of the for loop adding 100_000_000 elements to the *workQueue*, very rarely another Thread achieves to take an element from it. And so they are waiting most of the time until all *CounterClient*s are submitted.

The *ForkJoinPool* uses a more non-blocking way and as far as I understand multiple *WorkQueue*s for the submitted actions.